# How can I pack a snapshot into a string?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Can I pack a snapshot data from firebase into a string to use it anywhere else?

```
Firestore.instance
.collection('users')
.document(uid)
.collection('usergroups')
.snapshots(),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use snapshots because it will return stream if you want to to use somewhere else then you have to use getDocuments which will return future.

**Note**: as you get update of data in snapshot, you will not get in getDocuments.

How to use it.

```
 QuerySnapshot i =
        await Firestore.instance.collection("data").getDocuments();
    print(i.documents);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot> snapshots = Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(uid).collection('usergroups').snapshots()
```